# How to run mzscheme on DrRacket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have to make sure that my code is compatible with mzscheme but I don't know how to use it on my school's ssh servers. Is there anyway to test if my code is compatible with mzscheme on DrRacket?

Answer (score 4):

Rackets default language was renamed from `#!scheme` to `#!racket` when the whole thing changed name from PLT to Racket. `#!mzscheme` is an old version of this which is made as a [legacy language](http://docs.racket-lang.org/mzscheme/).

You switch language by making the language name the very first line in your source files. also instead of `#!language` you can write it more verbose as `#lang language`. It is exactly the same.

The legacy language uses the #!racket language pairs, which are immutable. Thus you cannot use `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` with the legacy library. If this is a problem use `#!r5rs` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The bin directory installed with DrRacket (i.e., `/Applications/Racket v6.3/bin` on Mac OS X) has `mzscheme` as a working binary; you can just use it.

Also on DrRacket GUI, you can specify to use MzScheme with `#lang mzscheme` at the first line.